# How do you specify the content of an element in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have XML that looks like this:

```
<Parameter Name="parameter name" Value="parameter value" />
```

which I defined in XSD like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="Parameter">
   <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
   <xs:attribute name="Value" type="xs:string" use="required" />
</xs:complexType>
```

but what I really want is the XML to look like this:

```
<Parameter Name="parameter name">parameter value<Parameter/>
```

I can't figure out how I do this in XSD. How would the XSD look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a complex element that can contain text only - in other words, text and attributes.

This is done using the "simpleContent" specifier, like so:

```
<xs:element name="Parameter">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with XML Schema the [primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/) should give you some starting point.